# 301 redirect in .htacces doesnt work:( Redesigned a site but cant get the old url's to link to new ones

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I redesigned this website, and tried to create a 301 redirect to redirect the old links to the new ones in order to save the existing google pagerank. I am using joomla for my site.

Example of a link i tried:

- Old link: `frutaplantaonline.nl/cgi-bin/index.pl?n=823&txt=privacy_policy`
- New link: `frutaplantaonline.nl/privacy-policy`

I tried:

```
Redirect 301 /cgi-bin/index.pl?n=823&txt=privacy_policy http://frutaplantaonline.nl/privacy-policy
RewriteRule ^/?cgi-bin/index.pl?n=823&txt=privacy_policy/?$ http://frutaplantaonline.nl/privacy-policy [L,R=301]
```

All the links have the `cgi-bin/index.pl` in it, if i remove the dot in `index.pl` i can redirect the site.

Have been searching for hours and hours but found no solution, I'd appreciate if someone can help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Redirect` directive in your case is uselsess as it works only on paths (i.e. `/cgi-bin/index.pl`).

You need to use `RewriteRule` directive and accompany it with `RewriteCond` to match against query string. From the [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> If you wish to match against the hostname, port, or query string, use a RewriteCond with the %{HTTP_HOST}, %{SERVER_PORT}, or %{QUERY_STRING} variables respectively.

So in your case something like this might do:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} n=823&txt=privacy_policy
RewriteRule ^/cgi-bin/index.pl$ http://frutaplantaonline.nl/privacy-policy [R=301,L]
```